# How can I use a Xerox DocuMate 510 scanner with Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, scanner, peripherals

I have a Xerox DocuMate scanner that I had used on Windows 7. I've recently upgraded to Windows 10.

I see the scanner as installed in the printers part of the settings, but I can no longer find the software used to scan images.

I've looked [here](http://www.xeroxscanners.com/en/us/products/DM510/drivers.asp) for drivers, and installed the One Touch software there, but cannot find to run it after supposedly successfully installing it.

Is there any hope of scanning documents from this scanner to this latest and greatest Windows OS? Or am I in the market for a new scanner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having used and administered Xerox DocuMate scanners and OneTouch software (though not this specific model, and not with Windows 10), I can say that **the order in which you install the scanner drivers and the OneTouch software** is important.  I imagine your upgrade to Windows 10 may have "refreshed" the drivers, thus putting things out of order and causing the whole thing to not work anymore.

I found that typically, when things go wrong with the software, the most effective course is to:

1. Uninstall OneTouch, uninstall the Xerox DocuMate drivers, and uninstall PaperPort (if you're using it).
2. Reboot your computer.
3. If you have the installation CD, use that to walk you through reinstalling the drivers and software.  If you do not have the original CD, then you'll want to install things in this order: Drivers, then OneTouch, then PaperPort (if you're using it).